# Debug Stored Procedure in SQL Server using breakpoint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, debugging

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is called from Excel file using ADODB.

I want to set a breakpoint on some line in SSMS in the stored procedure, just like I do in Visual Studio with C# code and then debug. I mean simply wait when debugger stops at the breakpoint.

I have an option to use SQL Server profiler to grab the stored procedure call with parameters and then simply paste the call to SSMS but I wonder if there is direct way.

Comment: Have you tried SSMS Studio and [debug](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/23/debugging-sql-queries-function-amp-stored-procedures-with-sql-management-studio)?

Comment: Your article does not address the question how to set breakpoint sit and wait until excel will call yuor SP. It simply states you can start the debugger and call you SP passing all parameters on your own. I have already written that in the last paragraph.

Comment: You should be able to debug SQL while debugging c# code.  Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-in-vs-2015

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DECLARE @val INT = 0;
Why don't you use PRINT 'My Value' + CAST(@val AS VARCHAR(MAX)) to debug the values?