# Cannot execute breakpoint inside stored procedure from VS 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints

I'm sure that I'm missing something very obvious, but it is escaping me.

I am trying to debug a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2012 database on a development machine. I am using VS 2017 Professional on my local machine. I am able to set a breakpoint and debug the stored procedure via SQL Server Object Explorer by feeding in a parameter value.

**HOWEVER**: I want to debug the stored procedure from my web application running in VS 2017 using IISExpress. I'm set up thusly:

- I am using the same connection string for both Server Explorer connection as well as the web application.
- The user has admin privileges in SQL Server
- In the property pages for the web application, I have the debuggers checked for "ASP.NET" and "SQL Server"
- I have the configuration manager set for Debug on Any CPU.
- When I run the application, I set a breakpoint before and after the call to the stored procedure.

When I run the application, it breaks at the breakpoint before the call to the stored procedure, but skips right around it to the next application breakpoint. The breakpoint in the stored procedure has is a hollow circle with the message
'The breakpoint will currently not be hit. Unable to bind sql breakpoint at this time. Object containing the breakpoint not loaded.'

I know that I can simply break inside the web application, grab the parameter value for the stored procedure and run it from the SQL Server Object Explorer to step through the code, but I shouldn't have to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enable the **Allow SQL/CLR Debugging** on the Data Connection on which the stored procedure is called? Please check the some more details steps from this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-in-vs-2015?noredirect=1&lq=1. Besides, if you are debug from a remote machine. you should logging into the Server Computer and debugging locally. BTW, there is a document about How to debug stored procedures in Visual Studio .NET: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/316549/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-net

Comment: Thanks. I have enabled the allow SQL/CLR debugging on the data connection. I am running the application which calls the Stored Procedure locally but the server on which the SQL Server instance is located is unavailable to me, so I cannot debug on it. It seems odd that I can debug the stored procecure if I execute it directly from the Sql Server Objects view but not from the managed code that also calls it?

Comment: @Jerry Mollis, Would you please share us the latest information in your side? If you submit this feedback, please share us the link in your answer here, so we could help you vote it.

Answer (score 0):

I test it with a simple sample, I could hit the breakpoint with VS2015, but not work in VS2017, so it would be a feedback.

[image]

If possible, I suggest you post a feedback to the developer community site directly:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The important step to get this working for me was:

- Don't run the C# code (Integration Tests in my case) using Resharper's test runner, use the standard Visual Studio test runner.

That solved it for me. The Resharper test runner for some reason didn't trigger the T-SQL debugging.

Since it doesn't sound like your issue was specifically to do with integration tests this may or may not help you exactly, posting in case it's useful.

(Using VS2019 with Resharper 2020.2.4).