# Why aren't my breakpoints hitting SQL In Visual Studio 2019 debugging script from network server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

So I am unfortunate enough to work in an organization who uses SSMS18, meaning I don't have the built-in debugger for SSMS. I am relegated to using VS2019 Professional to set break points and step through stored procedures. No Biggie, right?

Well when I select "Execute with Debugger" (can't see the selection in GIF for some reason) it loads then executes and never hits my breakpoint.

**I followed these posts below to no avail.**

[How to debug stored procedure in VS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885855/how-to-debug-stored-procedure-in-vs-2015?noredirect=1&lq=1)
This one I could not find what he was describing in step 6, but I debugged a SQL-Query in VS2019 before, but that was a local instance and not a remote server like it is in this case.

[Cannot execute breakpoint inside stored procedure from VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673403/cannot-execute-breakpoint-inside-stored-procedure-from-vs-2017)

**below is a gif of what is happening**
[image: Me attempting to debug]

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you access the sql database in `sql server explorer`? Please make sure that you can connected the database. In my side, l create a procedure and then use `Execute with Debugger`, the breakpoint can be hit. So if l misunderstand your issue, please share more detailed info. Thanks!

Comment: yes I can access the database in SQL Explorer. I hit "Execute with Debugger" for whatever reason in the video capture I made it doesn't show the menu when I select the own arrow next to the green arrow.

Comment: I installed a SSMS17 and have been debugging in SSMS instead. IT can succ it.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I try to debug a query in VS2019, and all of the breakpoints are yellow with the message indicating they will not be hit.  Impossible to step through.  Guess I'll have to download the old version of SSMS.  Microsoft can really screw things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and Install a version of SSMS < version 18. Then you will be able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have my database on another system and I want to debug remotely using visual studio 2019. Setting up a connection works to the database but debugging a stored procedure does not work. I get a message box indicating 'Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger, could not connect to the Database Engine instance 'servername\instancename'. Make sure you have enabled the debugging firewall exceptions and are using a login that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role. Click Help for more information.
The user that I am using has sysadmin role, checked it using the 'SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', 'YourLogin') command. I have disable the firewall on the remote machine. Locally I have enabled port 1433, 1434 and 135. Unfortunately this does not resolves the issue.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then remembered reading about Debugging firewall ports when I installed SQLServer 2019.

With SS 2014 I didn't get any error messages but when I tried to debug with SS2019 it said possible firewall block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/s0fk6z6e(v=vs.100)

Answer (score -1):

> Why aren't my breakpoints hitting SQL In Visual Studio 2019 debugging
>   script from network server

According to your issue, you can try to follow my steps:

**One**

1) connect the database in SQL Server Explorer and make sure you can access the data successfully.

2) right-click on the selected procedure and  choose **Execute Procedure** Option. Then it will open a new query window where you can execute your stored procedure as shown below.

**An easy way** is that you can just choose **Debug Procedure**, it will debug your procedure directly and you should not follow the below steps.

3) set a new breakpoint in the query file and select `Execute with Debugger`.**Since** you cannot open the green arrow's drop-down box, you can select the menu on the top by`SQL-->Execute with Debugger` to debug your procedure.

Besides, please remember to select the right database before debugging so that you don't run debug statements against other databases.

**Note: If your stored procedure requires parameters as input, Visual Studio will prompt you to enter the values before opening the new query window.**

More info you can refer to [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/24/debug-stored-procedures/).

**Two**

1) Right-click on the Project in the `Solution Explorer`-->`Add--> Script-->Script(Not in Build)`.

2) Write a custom query to select your procedure like `exec dbo.Users_GetUserInfo` and then choose `SQL-->Execute with Debugger`.

Hope it could help you.